# Display the most used search terms

Tags: 2013, search

Is there an OOB way to display the most used search terms within SharePoint 2013? Or would I have to rely on either a 3rd party or some custom solution?

Comment: I think something similar was asked before: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/67902/how-do-i-fetch-the-most-popular-search-terms

Comment: Yes I have seen that but was under the impression that it was referring to SharePoint 2010. Maybe something has changed in 2013 (which I suppose it hasn't).